# What's a ''Rubbelloseadventskalendar"?

Tags: meaning

No luck with the dictionary alone. 
I suppose this is some kind of Adventskalender (Advent calendar), but what makes it different?

Answer (score 6):

It's an advent calendar containing scratch cards.

> No luck with the dictionary alone.

That's often the case, since German allows to combine multiple words (nouns) into a single one almost arbitrarily.

Comment: So, Rubellos, also in other contexts, is just a scratch card? But is -los here the prefix = -less?

Comment: Hint to the OP: If you recognize parts of a compound noun, check your dictionary / web translator / ... for the rest. If you can dissect that further, even better ;-)

Comment: @Stephie: I was misguided as I thought there was something called "Rubbel", which had a variant without it "Rubbel-los". Now I see it's a name "Rubbellos"

Comment: Now think of a *Rubellos*. Or or of being *rubellos*.

Comment: @AnthonyCassidy there is indeed the verb _rubbeln_, which specifies the noun _Los_ in your example.

Comment: The calendar does not contain simple scratch cards, but lottery scratch tickets. So you have 24 times the chance to win something.

Answer (score 4):

German uses a mechanism to create new expressions that is not used in English and most other languages (at least not used as extend as in German): **compound words.** We just join together the words that we need, and often we also fill one or two additional letters into the gap to make it sound better.

Some famous examples:

- > [Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaft)
  >   danube steamboat shipping company
- > [Verkehrsinfrastrukturfinanzierungsgesellschaft](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verkehrsinfrastrukturfinanzierungsgesellschaft)
  >   traffic infrastructure financing company
- > [Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rinderkennzeichnungs-_und_Rindfleischetikettierungs%C3%BCberwachungsaufgaben%C3%BCbertragungsgesetz)
  >   beef labeling supervision duties delegation law
- > [Grundstücksverkehrsgenehmigungszuständigkeitsübertragungsverordnung](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Grundst%C3%BCcksverkehrsgenehmigungszust%C3%A4ndigkeits%C3%BCbertragungsverordnung)
  >   estate traffic licensing duties delegation edict

German dictionaries would explode, if every possible compound word would be listed in them. So you will find only some really common compound words in them.

The normal way too look up such words in dictionaries is to separate them into their parts and look for those parts, and then try to make sense out of the fact that those parts build a compound word.

In case of *»Rubbelloseadventskalender«* (note, that it has to be *∙d**e**r* at the end instead of *∙d**a**r*!) you get two major parts:

> - Rubbellose
> - Adventskalender

---

### Rubbellose

The first word is the plural of *»Rubbellos«*, and it is a compound word on its own. It is built from a verb and a noun:

> - rubbeln (to rub, to scratch)
> - Los (lottery ticket)

But *Rubbellos* is a word that is so common, that you can find it in almost every dictionary:
[Rubbellos in dict.leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/Rubbellos)

So now we have:

> Rubbellose = lottery scratch tickets

---

### Adventskalender

This also is a very common compound noun, so you will find it in its compound form in any dictionary, but lets have a look at its parts before:

- Advent (Advent)
- Kalender (calendar)

Note, that in Advent**s**kalender there is an S that is neither part of *Advent* nor of *Kalender*. It is there as some kind of glue, because people in Germany think it is easier to pronounce the compound word when there is an S. But people in Austria disagree, so they don't use an S in *Adventkalender*. (This is just one of thousands of tiny differences between Austrian and German German.)

You can find both versions in good dictionaries:

> - [Adventskalender](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/Adventskalender) = Advent calendar
> - [Adventkalender](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/Adventkalender) = Advent calendar

---

### complete word *Rubbelloseadventskalendar*

So the complete word is:

> lottery scratch tickets Advent calendar

This can be an Advent calendar that has lottery scratch tickets in it's boxes, or a calendar that has 24 scratch fields, each of them a lottery ticket, or what ever you might think the combination of *lottery scratch tickets* plus *Advent calendar* could be.