# Weiberworte: what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, compound

I came across this in the title of a fairly tale:

> Weiberworte trennen Fleisch und Bein.

None of the standard translation sites I used gave a satisfactory answer (if any at all). Thanks.

Comment: Related question: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48522/whats-a-rubbelloseadventskalendar

Comment: I think it's also noteworthy, that in this case Bein should be translated/understood as bone, not leg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Weiberworte: what does it mean?

It means *women's words*, refering to *words spoken by women*. 
The english title of the chinese fairy tale is indeed *women's words part flesh and blood*, as for example displayed on [wikisource](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Chinese_Fairy_Book_(Richard_Wilhelm)/1). 
When dealing with compound words like this (that you won't find in a dictionary sometimes), you should always try to figure out the individual words and their translation, which helps you to conclude the meaning of the compound word. 
Here *Weib* is an antiquated word for *wife* or in general *women* and *worte* translates to *words*. 
You can find a more elaborated explanation of compound words, and how to deal with them, in [Hubert Schölnast](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/1487/hubert-sch%C3%B6lnast)'s       answer to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48522/whats-a-rubbelloseadventskalendar).

Comment: So, I read the story, and it seems to mean "The wife's words".  I thought that perhaps this is an idiom with deeper meaning.  However, the story is either very poorly translated into German, or it's a bad story. Either way, the title has little to do with the content. Thanks.